# Activating ssl on tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat, server-crashes

I want to encrypt the http traffic on a tomcat instance via ssl. Therefore I followed the most simplistic approach described on various webpages. But anyway it simply does not work. Here is what I did:

1. "keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA" and I enterd "changeit" as the password (since this is the defaut chosen by tomcat)
2. Altering $CATALINA_HOME/conf/servers.xml by uncommenting the following line

   Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/
3. Restarting tomcat

Entering

```
https://localhost:8443
```

does not work. However, I can still access the page via normal http like

```
http://localhost:8080
```

The logfile does not contain any suspicious information.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the keyfile in your connector like

keystoreFile="/keystorepath/.keystore" keystorePass="password"

Check this tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I already did that and I also had a look at several tutorials on the net such the one you posted. They are all not correct or a least they are missing something. But what is this something?

Comment: Okay, I got it. There is nothing wrong with the tutorials. I just simply had an error in my shorewall firewall configuration.